# How to (properly) use the ExtendRtspStream command in Google's Nest Device Access API?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, nest-device-access

Using Google's [Nest Device Access API](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api), I can generate an RTSP camera stream using the [`GenerateRtspStream` command](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#generatertspstream) and subsequently stop the stream using the `StopRtspStream` command. Makes sense, however these streams are only alive for 5 minutes by default - so the API also features another command: [`ExtendRtspStream`](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#extendrtspstream).

On the face of it, this sounds like it should "extend" the stream you had originally created, however these RTSP stream urls include an `auth` query parameter and extending a stream simply issues a new token to use for this, which means that **the url for the stream changes every time it gets extended**. So in reality the stream isn't getting extended at all as the url you use to access the stream still gets invalidated, and you have to restart it with a new url to continue watching the stream. So what's the point? You may as well just call the `GenerateRtspStream` command and switch over to that one once the first expires. Is there some way to seamlessly change the RTSP url mid-stream that I'm not aware of using FFMPEG, perhaps? Or to have a proxy server that broadcasts a static RTSP url and seamlessly switches the actual url each time it gets extended?

---

Rant starts here: I'm really hoping that this behaviour is actually a bug or oversight in the design of the API, and that `ExtendRtspStream` is supposed to keep the same url alive for as long as needed, because it's awfully pointless to have an RTSP stream that only stays alive for a max of 5 minutes. Heck, it'd be more useful to have an API that just returns the latest single-image snapshot from the camera every 10 seconds or so - but alas, there's no API for that either.

Comment: Did you find a way extend the stream without invalidating it?

Comment: No, I haven’t been able to find anyone to contact to confirm if this behaviour is intentional or not (and if it is, how they expect anyone to actually use it)

Comment: I see. Well at least it's consistent with the SDM API being awful to use.

Comment: FWIW, my solution was to start another subscriber in parallel staggered ~3 minutes out (3 minutes because it can take a while for the feed to start). I'm only interested in the audio, so I do a cross correlation between adjacent clips to find when they overlap, and merge the clips for one continuous segment.

Comment: Clever! That's the sort of thing you'd think you wouldn't have to resort to, but glad you found a way to do it

Comment: Can you open a ticket on the Public Issue Tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com) ? Please attach the logs for your issue as it will help us in analysis of the issue.

Comment: @SiddhantPriyadarshi Sorry, but no. I no longer own Nest devices and lost interest in trying to make this work a long time ago.